# Post route returning nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I've been following a guide on implementing a password reset in Node. I'm working on the password reset post route below and when I post nothing seems to happen, it justs reloads the reset page. ive added some console.log() in various places on the code but they dont get executed. Hope someone can assist. ive deleted the other routes to make the code shorter

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
var Kids = require('../models/kid');
var User = require('../models/user');
var async = require('async');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var middleware = require('../middleware');


//password reset
router.get('/password_reset', function (req, res) {
    res.render('password_reset');
    
});

//posting the account email reset
router.post('/password_reset', function (req, res, next) {
    async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
        var token = buf.toString('hex');
        done(err, token);
      });
    },
        
    function(token, done) {
      User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          req.flash('error', 'No account with that email address exists.');
          return res.redirect('/forgot');
        }

        user.resetPasswordToken = token;
        user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

        user.save(function(err) {
          done(err, token, user);
        });
      });
    },
    function(token, user, done) {
      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
        service: 'SendGrid',
        auth: {
          user: 'Hidden',
          pass: 'Hidden'
        }
      });
      var mailOptions = {
        to: user.email,
        from: 'passwordreset@demo.com',
        subject: 'Node.js Password Reset',
        text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
          'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
          'http://' + req.headers.host + '/reset/' + token + '\n\n' +
          'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
      };
      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
        req.flash('info', 'An e-mail has been sent to ' + user.email + ' with further instructions.');
        done(err, 'done');
      });
    }
  ], function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.redirect('/forgot_reset');
  });
});



module.exports = router;
```

Comment: why don't you use `async/await`?

Comment: @Anatoly im not sure how i would do it

Comment: I deleted my answer, but I think it's better delete async.waterfall, and use another approach for reset_password

Comment: your problem is about token because it's undefined in next steps

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the issue, it was to do with my form. I had forgotten to add:

```
<form method="post" action="/password_reset">
```

so the form was not sending anything.